# Passing views, or higher-order components, in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, reactjs, swiftui

As someone who knows React, coming to SwiftUI I'm having challenges to find the right abstractions. Here's an example, but my question is more general. It's related to passing views or, what the React community calls, higher-order components. My example is below. TLDR: how do I abstract and remove duplication in the list views below?

Some models (these will differ in the end):

```swift
struct Apple: Comparable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let label: String

    static func < (lhs: Apple, rhs: Apple) -> Bool {
        lhs.label < rhs.label
    }
}

struct Banana: Comparable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let label: String

    static func < (lhs: Banana, rhs: Banana) -> Bool {
        lhs.label < rhs.label
    }
}
```

Some basic detail views (these will differ in the end):

```swift
struct AppleView: View {
    let apple: Apple

    var body: some View {
        Text(apple.label)
    }
}

struct BananaView: View {
    let banana: Banana

    var body: some View {
        Text(banana.label)
    }
}
```

And two list views with a lot of duplication:

```swift
struct AppleListView: View {
    let title: String
    let apples: [Apple]

    var body: some View {
        List(apples.sorted()) { apple in
            NavigationLink(destination: AppleView(apple: apple)) {
                Text(apple.label)
                    .padding(.all)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(title), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct BananaListView: View {
    let title: String
    let bananas: [Banana]

    var body: some View {
        List(bananas.sorted()) { banana in
            NavigationLink(destination: BananaView(banana: banana))
                Text(banana.label)
                    .padding(.all)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(title), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

As you can see, it differs only in small parts. The type of the collection differs and the `destination` view. I want to remain flexible when it comes to this `destination` view as `Apple` and `Banana`, and their detail views above, will differ in the end. Furthermore it's likely that I want to add `Cherry` later on, so there's value in abstracting this list view.

So, my question is: how can I best abstract the list views above and remove the duplication in there? What would you suggest? My attempts are below, but it leaves me with type errors. It touches on the higher-order component idea, mentioned earlier.

My attempt with type errors:

```swift
struct AppleListView: View {
    let title: String
    let apples: [Apple]

    var body: some View {
        ListView(
            title: title,
            rows: apples, // it complains about types here -> `Cannot convert value of type '[Apple]' to expected argument type 'Array<_>'`
            rowView: { apple in Text(apple.label) },
            destinationView: { apple in AppleView(apple: apple) }
        )
    }
}

struct BananaListView: View {
    let title: String
    let bananas: [Banana]

    var body: some View {
        ListView(
            title: title,
            rows: bananas, // it complains about types here -> `Cannot convert value of type '[Banana]' to expected argument type 'Array<_>'`
            rowView: { banana in Text(banana.label) },
            destinationView: { banana in BananaView(banana: banana) }
        )
    }
}

struct ListView<Content: View, Row: Comparable & Identifiable>: View {
    let title: String
    let rows: [Row]
    let rowView: (Row) -> Content
    let destinationView: (Row) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        List(rows.sorted()) { row in
            NavigationLink(destination: self.destinationView(row)) {
                self.rowView(row)
                    .padding(.all)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(title), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you made same type for Label and Destination, here is fixed variant

```
struct ListView<Target: View, Label: View, Row: Comparable & Identifiable>: View {
    let title: String
    let rows: [Row]
    let rowView: (Row) -> Label
    let destinationView: (Row) -> Target

    var body: some View {
        List(rows.sorted()) { row in
            NavigationLink(destination: self.destinationView(row)) {
                self.rowView(row)
                    .padding(.all)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(title), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Why can't `rowView` and `destinationView` have the same type?

Comment: @kodnin, they can, but can also be different, as in your case - Label is Text but Destination is either BananaView or AppleView. So generic should be declare possibility of generic variant, ie. different types.

Comment: Ok! So it can't infer that both `AppleView` and `BananaView` also return `Text`, as `rowView` does?